# Plotting the same curve in different graphs

Tags: plotting

I've got a list of plots of the same curve with different colors in a variable called `bifcurveplot`. To plot them all together is senseless because I will miss the colors so I would like to plot each of them in a different figure. Just as an example, I am doing something like this:

```
bifcurveplot = {};
For[i = 1, i <= 2, i++,
 AppendTo[bifcurveplot, {}];
 For[j = 1, j <= 2, j++,
  tempplot = 
   ParametricPlot[{If[i == 1 && j == 1, {t, t}], 
     If[i == 1 && j == 2, {t, t}], If[i == 2, {t, t}]}, {t, 0, 1}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red, Orange}];
  AppendTo[bifcurveplot[[i]], tempplot];
  ]
 ]
```

The problem is that then I try to use the following command:

```
For[i = 1, i <= 2, i++,
 For[j = 1, j <= 2, j++,
  Show[bifcurveplot[[i]][[j]]]
  ]
 ]
```

but I get no output. On the other hand, if I try with

```
Show[bifcurveplot]
```

I only get the following output:

[image: Output]

which doesn't show the set of colors I have used in each case. The question is: can I plot the graphs in different figures in order to see the colors? Note that this is only an example that shows what my problem is.

Comment: How many plots do you have? Have you explored `GraphicsGrid` ?

Comment: In this case, I've got three plots. I could plot them manually but in the future I could get more plots so to do that manually is not the best idea

Comment: `plots = Table[
  Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, PlotStyle -> RandomColor[]], {8}]` ? and e.g., `plots[[3]]` would be the third plot. Also try: `GraphicsGrid[Partition[plots, 2]]` and `GraphicsGrid[Partition[plots, UpTo[3]]]`

Comment: I have tried with those options but still, I cannot see the plots in full as if I plot them separately. I edited the question just to explain the idea a little better

Comment: Difference in color means a difference in the data that is being plotted. I don't think I understand this particular problem.

Comment: Please post your code about your two plot.

Comment: To post the whole code would be a mess. I just posted an explanation of my problem with an example. Hopefully, that will make it clear. Let me know if there's anything unclear.

Comment: `GraphicsGrid[bifcurveplot]` works for your new edit so what was your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Row[(Show[#1, ImageSize -> Small] & ) /@ Flatten[bifcurveplot]]
```

[image]

You can change the size of each plot by adjusting the `ImageSize` option.

Or you can just write `bifcurveplot` and evaluate it,it will show your plots.

[image]